# How can I trigger a function after a review is made in my WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, triggers, action

I want to write some code for a plugin that after a review is made from a user, (`wp_comments` table gets updated) it triggers a function that tells it to do something.

How can I know if a new review is made since reviews are saved to the db as comments with a `comment_type` = 'review'?

Thank you!

Comment: That depends. What are you using for reviews? Is it Woocommerce?

Comment: Yes woocommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [comment_post action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/) to perform an action when a new review is created:

```
/**
 * Performs an action after a review has been created.
 *
 * @param   int         $comment_ID
 * @param   int|string  $comment_approved (1 if approved, 0 if not, 'spam' if spam)
 * @param   array       $commentdata
 */
function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata ) {
    if ( 'review' == $commentdata['comment_type'] ) {
        // A new review has been created, do something here.
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 3 );
```

The `$commentdata` array would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [comment_post_ID] => 16
    [comment_author] => John Doe
    [comment_author_email] => me@example.com
    [comment_author_url] => 
    [comment_content] => My awesome review!
    [comment_type] => review
    [comment_parent] => 0
    [user_ID] => 1
    [user_id] => 1
    [comment_author_IP] => ::1
    [comment_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
    [comment_date] => 2019-04-13 14:11:45
    [comment_date_gmt] => 2019-04-13 14:11:45
    [filtered] => 1
    [comment_approved] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks it works this way, but I get 2 warnings.Warning: Illegal string offset 'comment_type' 
and
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Comment: I don't see any PHP warning/error messages with the code from my answer so it must be something on your side. If you share your code I might be able to help you debug it (but for that you'll probably have to ask a new question).